# socket.io emitting multiple messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

For some reason, socket.io is emitting multiple messages when it should be emitting only one. This also causes a disconnect I think. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
var Campfire = require("../lib/campfire").Campfire,
    express = require("express"),
    app =  require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(1337);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/tpl');
app.set('view engine', "jade");
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("page");
});

// catch all random errors and print them out
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err){
  console.error(err);
});

var instance = new Campfire({
  ssl     : true,
  token   : "MYTOKEN",
  account : "MYACCOUNT"
});


//////////////////
// EMPLOYEES
//////////////////
var lukasz = {name: "Lukasz", id: 1216806, status: ""};
var dana = {name: "Dana", id: 1054576, status: ""};
var users = [lukasz, dana];

function returnUsernameUsingID(userID){
    for (var j=0; j<users.length; j++) {
        if (users[j].id == userID) return users[j].name;
    }
    return -1;
}

function wordIsInSentence(theWord, theSentence){
  if (theSentence.indexOf(theWord) > -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
////////////////
// Campfire API
////////////////

instance.join(571821, function(error, room) {
  room.listen(function(message) {
    var username = returnUsernameUsingID(message.userId);
    if (wordIsInSentence("wfh", message.body)) {
      room.speak(username+" is working from home");
      io.sockets.emit('message', { message: username+",wfh" });
    }else if (wordIsInSentence("back", message.body)) {
      room.speak(username+" is back");
      io.sockets.emit('message', { message: username+",back" });
    }else if (wordIsInSentence("out", message.body)) {
      room.speak(username+" is out");
      io.sockets.emit('message', { message: username+",out" });
    }else if (wordIsInSentence("help", message.body)) {
      console.log(message);
      room.speak("your user ID is: "+message.userId+"\n/wfh - working from home \n/back - in office and available \n/headsdown - in office but busy \n/sick - outsick \n/vacation - on vacation \n/out - out for the day");
    }else if (wordIsInSentence("id", message.body)) {
      console.log(message);
      room.speak("your user ID is: "+message.userId);
    }else {
      console.log("Received unknown message:");
      console.log(message);
    }
  });
});
```

https://gist.github.com/hilukasz/6526969

sometimes it is ok other times it will send multiple messages like so:

```
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"message":"Lukasz,back"}]}
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"message":"-1,back"}]}
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"message":"-1,back"}]}
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"message":"-1,back"}]}
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"message":"-1,back"}]}
```

Comment: You use both room.speak and io.sockes.emit. Can that be your problem? Otherwise can you give an example of what exactly is going wrong? Which message do you send, which return message do you expect, ...

Comment: room.speak writes a message to the chat room, and io.sockets.emit sends a message to socket, so they both do different things, you need socket to emit message in order for the room.speak to work (the conditional has to pass)

Comment: I updated the description with what happens when it starts doing weird things.

Comment: I have not. Spent a lot of time trying to figure it out, from sound of it, it might be issue with core node.js just haven't had time to track it down.